# Is there a function in JGraphT like k_edge_components() in networkx

Tags: java, jgrapht

A k-edge-connected component is a set of nodes which remain connected even after removing any k edges.
Is there a function can do this in JGraphT? If not, is there a java graph lib having this function?
[Take this figure for example, node {1, 2, 4} are still connected after removing any 3 edges in the graph, so {1, 2, 4} is a 3-edge-component of this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUGBT.png)

Comment: Would you mind specifying what the function `k_edge_components()`, computes, what the input is, and what the output is?

Comment: the input of k_edge_components() is a graph 'G' and an Integer 'k', and the output of it is all components of this graph that remain connected even after removing any k edges in the graph.